# How add video formats (360p, 480p, 720p etc) to HTML 5 video player?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

How add video formats (360p, 480p, 720p etc) to HTML 5 video player ?
functionaly like on youtube

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a video by using this code.
You can also change the width and height based on the format you need.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: but you can't select the video resolution from there)